# Auto-reshape road lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcmap, shapefile

Is there any Python code that will help me to reshape segments of roads in ArcGIS 10.3 like in the picture below? I tried to auto reshape with arcpy.Densify_edit tool but I don't have any result, just adding to my road line some vertices.

The code:

```
import arcpy arcpy.env.workspace = "CURRENT"
arcpy.Densify_edit("ROAD_C", "ANGLE","", "", "90")
```

And doens't do anything.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using the geoprocessing tool "Smooth Line":

[image]

Comment: Ok. That I am using now but writing a Python code. Thank you :)